# FTP in a bash doesn't manage correctly à è ì ò ù

Tags: iis, ftp, ascii

I have a problem inside my .sh file.

When executing the following commands:

```
ftp -v server.name.net
Connected to server.name.net
220 Microsoft FTP Service
ftp> ls
```

the result is

```
200 PORT command successful.
150 Opening ASCII mode data connection for file list.
2014_01_00500_Indennit▒ malattia.xlsx
```

and not `2014_01_00500_Indennità malattia.xlsx`

The same happens for the following characters: è, ì, ò, ù

Answer (score 0):

**The server is faulty** , or possibly it's not actualy an FTP server at all

according to RFC959 non-ASCII characters are illegal in filenames

```
        <pathname> ::= <string>
        <string> ::= <char> | <char><string>
        <char> ::= any of the 128 ASCII characters except <CR> and <LF>
```

Comment: About what I'd expect from microsoft.